# How to install FREETDS on Windows 10 using Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, installation, freetds, tiny-tds

I've tried to find a way to install freetds on windows, but i just cannot find that.

I'm trying to install tiny_tds but i got the error:

gem install tiny_tds

---

ERROR:  Error installing tiny_tds:

The last version of tiny_tds (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 
2.1.1. Try installing it with `gem install tiny_tds -v 2.1.1`

tiny_tds requires Ruby version < 2.5, >= 2.0. The current ruby version is 2.5.0.

---

I've tried 'gem install tiny_tds -v 2.1.1', same error.

My ruby version is ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]

I asked for my friend try to use my project on his machine(MAC) and he got the same error. So he just installed FreeTds and after that he could install tiny_tds.

I thought the gem Tiny_tds includes Freetds, but it is not happening. I believe i need to install FreeTds on windows.

Could someone explain how to install FreeTds on Windows? which tool is necessary? if it is command lines, which command should i use? Something complete.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like TinyTDS requires an earlier version of Ruby than you have, lower than `2.5`. You are running greater than `2.5`, version `2.5.1p57`.

I'd recommend installing the latest Ruby version of the `2.4` release and trying again. Good luck!

PS: If you need to install the FreeTDS Windows binaries directly, you can find them here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/